# Converting m4a to mp3 using sound converter on Network Attached Storage

Tags: sound, mp3, conversion, nas

I am trying to convert m4a files to mp3 for uploading to an mp3 player that doesn't support m4a. All my music is stored on a Buffalo Network Attached Storage (NAS) and I am using Soundconverter. Ideally I would like to use Soundconverter directly on the files on the NAS, and have them convert to mp3 back to a folder on the NAS.

I have tried to do this directly through Soundconverter. I can navigate to the m4a files on the NAS through Soundconverter, but when I try and move them into the conversion window either by dragging and dropping or double clicking, the conversion window goes pink and nothing happens (there is no error message associated with this).

However, I can get Soundconverter to work by moving the m4a files onto the hard drive of my PC, converting them there and then copying the mp3 back to the NAS. This adds significantly to the time and administration of the task.

I have tried changing the NAS read/write permissions to no avail.

Does anyone know of a way of achieving my aim directly?

Please be gentle as I am a very new convert to Ubuntu/Linux as a result of Windows fatigue. Loving it so far but this is my first attempt at branching out into the great unknown.